# getting an error when fetching a json or xml data from a url using jquery-ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var user_key = "asdflk134";
        var app_key = "pigasdb95r91bva";
        var params = "app_key="+app_key+"&user_key="+user_key+"&format=xml";

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://hellotxt.com/api/method/user.latest",
            data: params,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(data){
                jQuery(".result").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

When checking on my firebug console, I noticed this error:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{3d9469e7-683c-41ea-9bd4-c761a0568b30} Line Number 1, Column 1:

^
```

What do you think is this error? I'm really stuck on this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded! Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you check the XHR sub tab under the Net tab in Firebug and show us the data in the response? I'm also curious why the data type is "text" in the Ajax call, when it seems like your trying to return XML (any reason why the data type isn't XML?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed the dataType into xml but still the same result. Here's the XHR from firebug:
There's no response in the XHR. And in the XML Tab there's that error:
`XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{0d5cfb18-8205-4631-bcd8-6b4aaffc3fe2} Line Number 1, Column 1:

^`

Comment: Did you try to go to that URL directly in your browser? I got valid XML that says `<rsp status="FAIL"><message>app key not specified</message></rsp>`

Comment: It might be due to  Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Are you calling it from the same domain or your local server?

Comment: Yes, you got that error because you didn't specify an app_key, but if you'll use a form with an app_key in the field, you won't get that error. I'm not having a problem when I use an ordinary submit button, but when I use ajax, there's that problem arises wherein this error comes out `XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{0d5cfb18-8205-4631-bcd8-6b4aaffc3fe2} Line Number 1, Column 1: ^`

Comment: @IdoGreen: I'm calling it from another domain. its like, my own domain is http://mydomain.com then when I use ajax, I call it at http://hellotxt.com/api/method/user.latest. Is that a problem? if yes, what do you think would be the solution? 
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

try to change the code that you have do it this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var user_key = "asdflk134";
            var app_key = "pigasdb95r91bva";
            var params = "app_key="+app_key+"&user_key="+user_key+"&format=xml";

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://hellotxt.com/api/method/user.latest",
                data: {
"user_key": user_key,
"app_key":app_key,
"format":"xml"},
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(data){
                    jQuery(".result").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

you should submit an object to your data parameter for jquery to read it properly `<key>:<value>` the key will be taken as the parameter name.

Comment: Thanks Sir Chris! Miss you guys! ;) I better test it. ;)

Comment: no problem elson hope you could have sometime to visit our office again. ;)

Comment: Hahaha! you just changed the way I pass the variable into the url. Thanks anyway, very much appreciated! ;)